# Can not see anything on my Laptop display

Tags: laptop, display, laptop-repair

I have a Compaq CQ40 Laptop. I cannot see anything on the display except some black/white lines or a black screen. After searching, I found that there is a tiny gap in the screen. I had changed the panel before a few months ago. I think it was not properly closed after repairing. It works fine when I connect to external source or It will work properly if i hold the top of the screen tight with my fingers and when I leave the fingers from the screen, whatever in the screen remains unchanged .

Please forgive if my question is a stupid one. I'm really weak about the laptop hardware issues. Can anyone help me to identify the problem and resolve it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like a loose connection. Have you taken it apart again and check the connectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you got yourself a bad screen. I was going to suggest the backlight but usually with the backlight you shouldn't be getting any lines all it will do is dim your screen so you can barely see anything. But since you got the black and white lines for sure you have a defective screen is it under warranty? I would reach out to whom ever you bought it from and get it replaced.

good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I've given it for repair and that guys telling it's chip and panel should be replaced.

Comment: @Anand sounds like either the video chip is going bad (and the repair procedure is typically called a "re-flow" (extremely common on the HP dv series, from which your Compaq is derived). It could also be the backlight on the screen or the inverter. If it's the backlight or inverter, usually this is a trivial task to replace and not all that expensive (depending on where you take it). If its a re-flow, be prepared for the repair to not last very long. Back in my PC repair days, we'd have majority come back busted again within 6 months.

Answer (score 1):

either a loose connection or bad screen -- since you can output to external display no problems, this is a good sign. I'd open it back up if possible and check the cable that plugs into the mobo from the display. My bet is either it's loose, but got pinched somehow. If it was not put back together properly, the cable could have gotten pinched in the hinges and cause it to go out.

Luckily if the cable's all you need they typically can be found on ebay for cheap.